# Reading in two steps from the same pipe

Tags: c, linux, process, pipe, fork

So, basically I have a piece of code where a parent process prints numbers     to the pipe:

```
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            {
                j=i+1;
                nwrite=write(pa[1],&j,sizeof(j));
                if (nwrite==-1)
                        {
                    printf("\nWrite error,pipe closed\n");
                    exit(-1);
                        }
                if (nwrite==0)
                        {
                    printf("\nWrote 0!\n");
                    break;
                        }
            }
```

and a child that reads from this pipe in two different steps: 
It first reads all the even numbers and writes them to the pipe `pb`:

```
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            { 
                nread=read(pa[0],&num,sizeof(num));
                if (nread==0)
                {
                    printf("\nNothing to read!\n");
                    break;
                }
                if (nread==-1)
                {
                    printf("\nRead error!\n");
                    exit(-1);
                }
                if (num%2==0)
               {
                        printf("\nPrinting on pipe pb: %d\n",num);
                        nwrite=write(pb[1],&num,sizeof(num));
                        if (nwrite==0)
                        {
                            printf("\nNothing to write!\n");
                            break;
                        }
                        if (nwrite==-1)
                        {
                            printf("\nwrite error!\n");
                            exit(-1);
                        }
                }
            }
```

then it goes in `pause()` and waits for another process to send a `signal(SIGUSR1,handler);`
After receiving the signal, it continues its execution
reading all the odd numbers from the pipe and writing them to the `pb` pipe:

```
          for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            { 
                nread=read(pa[0],&num,sizeof(num));
                if (nread==0)
                {
                    printf("\nNothing to read!\n");
                    break;
                }
                if (nread==-1)
                {
                    printf("\nRead error!\n");
                    exit(-1);
                }
                if (num%2==1)
                {
                        printf("\nPrinting on pipe pb: %d\n",num);
                        nwrite=write(pb[1],&num,sizeof(num));
                        if (nwrite==0)
                        {
                            printf("\nNothing to write!\n");
                            break;
                        }
                        if (nwrite==-1)
                        {
                            printf("\nwrite error!\n");
                            exit(-1);
                        }
                 }
            }
```

The thing is, the first `read` call to the pipe `pa` (where I get even numebrs) reads all the pipe content. Thereafter, the second `read` call from the pipe `pa`  returns 0 because all the numbers have been read.I would like to read just the even numbers in the first step and then the odd numbers in the second step,and I can't do that making the parent write only even numbers.
Any tip? Thank you all.

`I am really sorry for my bad indenting, I'm trying my best to solve this issue with my coding style.`

Comment: You can't. But you could read the data from the pipe and write it to a regular file, which would allow you to seek.  Or you could read the data and write it into two different pipes.  A good exercise might be to write the odd numbers into a pipe that you will read in the same thread...you will wind up blocking yourself when you have too much data, and it's a good exercise to understand that issue and figure out a resolution.

Comment: That's quite upsetting. I'm studying for an exam and it is explicitly written to use the same pipe and not other things like files etc. I think it could be an assignment error. Thank you by the way for your fast answer.

Comment: Perhaps the intent of the exercise is to have you store the odd numbers in memory, and  dynamically grow that memory.

Comment: The exercise should be all about pipes.... Well, never mind, I will try to figure out with my professor what should I do with this assignment. Thank  you, again.

Answer (score 1):

No seeking on a pipe.  End of story.

Please do not deliver error messages to standard output by using printf().  If using stdio.h, use fprintf and direct them to stderr.  Otherwise, temporarily switch out standard output for standard error, printf(), and restore:

> int   save_stdout;
>       save_stdout = dup( 1 );
>       close( 1 );
>       dup( 2 );
>
> printf( . . . );
>
> close( 1 );
>       dup(
>   save_stdout );

Comment: Duping the underlying file descriptors is a terrible idea!  Without proper flushing, you're going to end up with messages going to the wrong place.

Comment: Your use of `dup()` instead of `dup2()` to specify the number of the newly-created fd assumes the process is single-threaded (or else I think an `open` in another thread could take fd 1, besides the fact that another thread might print to stdout while you're doing this), and that `stdin` isn't closed.  (`./a.out <&-` to run a program with its stdin closed).

Comment: `dup2` also closes the old fd1 for you.  So in summary, `dup2(2,1)` would be much better, but still an ugly hack that you shouldn't use.